Sync fusion image viewer license is working fine in one project but not in second project. The license key is same, everything is same
I am working on angular 16 and both components in which sync fusion image viewer is integrated are standalone. Moreover, the license key is working fine, i have tested by making a separate new project.
Both project components are identical. So it must work in other project too.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

make sure you have installed same version of syncfusion in both project and syncfusion license key is generated for that version.

Upon reviewing your query, we understand that you are facing difficulties with registering a license in your application. Regarding this, if both project components are identical, the license key registration should be successful. However, if you are facing any problems, you should ensure that you are using the same major version for all Syncfusion components. Our Syncfusion licenses are version-specific, and if multiple major versions of our components are used in the same application, it can create version conflicts. Therefore, please make sure that you use the same version for all Syncfusion components. License key generated under same major version should be used.
However, kindly ensure that the license key registered as mentioned in the documentation using register method. we would like to convey that the "register license" method should be called from the root folder of the application. This step registers the license globally for our controls.
Documentation : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/licensing/license-key-registration
Additionally, this issue may occur due to duplicate packages installed in your application. Follow the below steps to resolve the issue.

Delete the @Syncfusion folder from node_modules and the package-lock.json file from the root folder.

Clear npm .cache file at your end.

Update our packages to the same major version. For example, if your utilizing version like (i.e. v25.X.XX) use the same version for all the Syncfusion components in the package.json file.

Run the ‘’npm install” command to install the node_modules.


Please refer our below documentation licensing FAQ's
Link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/licensing/licensing-troubleshoot#potential-causes-of-licensing-errors-in-applications
Hope this information resolves the issue.
